# dynamic jPlayer

Tags: jquery, javascript, jplayer

I've been trying for a week to create a dynamic jplayer that changes depending on the chosen option in a selectbox. Other Stack Overflow posts have been very helpful, so I hope I'll be able to figure this out. Any links to examples that other people have done would also be appreciated. The related javascript is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(function() {
        var pinyinTone=null;
        var toneSelect=null;
        var pinyinSound=null;
        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
            },
            swfPath: "/sites/all/libraries/jplayer/js",
            supplied: "mp3"
        })
        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: '/sites/default/files/pinyinSound/' + pinyinTone  + '.mp3',
            wav: '/sites/default/files/pinyinSound/' + pinyinTone  + '.wav'
        });
    };

    $("select#pinyinSound").change(function(){
        toneSelect=1;
        $('#toneSelectDiv').show();
        pinyinSound=$(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "/HBCAppFiles/get_list.php",
            data: {
                pinyinSound: $("select#pinyinSound").val()
            },
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(j){
                var options = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay +  '</option>';
                }
                $("select#toneSelect").html(options);
            }
        })
        pinyinTone=pinyinSound + toneSelect;
        processPinyinVars(pinyinTone);
    });

    $("img#pinyinSliderPlayButton").click(function (){
        $('#inner').animate({width: 250}, function(){ $(this).width(0)});
        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("play");
        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow complained when my code was indented more than 4 spaces...

Answer (score 3):

I figured out my problem... I decided to go about my problem a different way, and came to the solution a LOT quicker. I realized that I needed to access the selected element of a  statement with jquery. In order to do that, I needed to use the find function. What I came up with was this:

```
   $("#trackSelect").change(function(e) { 
       my_trackName.text($(this).val()); 
       my_jPlayer.jPlayer("setMedia", { 
          mp3: $(this).find(':selected').attr("href") 
       }); 
   });
```